# Golangのtemplateで配列を余りを均等にして3当分したい。

Tags: go, templates

タイトルのような事をしたいです。これをtemplateの計算でやるにはどのようにすればいいでしょうか。
`=`演算子があればif節の中で変数に代入できますが`=`演算子がないのでどうすれば良いのかわかりません。

```
{{ define "tiledView" }}
{{ $length := len . }}
/* 当分する単位を計算 */
{{ $divide := div $length 3}}
/* 余りを計算 */
{{ $m := mod $length 3 }}
{{ $end1 := add $divide 1 }}
{{ $m := sub $m 1 }}
{{ $end2 := add $end1 $divide }}
{{ $m := sub $m 1 }}
{{ $end3 := add $end2 $divide }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
        {{ range (slice . 0 $end1) }}
        {{ template "moviebox" . }}
        {{ end }}
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
        {{ range (slice . $end1 $end2) }}
        {{ template "moviebox" . }}
        {{ end }}
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
        {{ range (slice . $end2 $end3) }}
        {{ template "moviebox" . }}
        {{ end }}
    </div>
</div>
{{ end }}
```

各template functionの機能は下記のとおりです。

- add 第1引数に第2引数を足す
- sub 第1引数から第2引数を引く
- mod 余りを計算する
- div 割り算する
- slice スライスを指定の数でスライスしたものを返す。

余り`$m`が0になるまで`$end~`に1足していけば良いのですが、if節中で変数を定義できない(ローカルスコープのため)のでできません。

dataとしてコードから渡す事はできますが、コードがややこしくなるので、できればtemplateで処理したいのですが、方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
func RetOneOrZero(n int)int{
    if n > 0{
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

{{ define "tiledView" }}
{{ $length := len . }}
{{ $divide := div $length 3}}
{{ $m := mod $length 3 }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
        {{ $p := rioz $m }}
        {{ $m := sub $m 1 }}
        {{ $end1 := add $divide $p }}
        {{ range (slice . 0  $end1) }}
        {{ template "moviebox" . }}
        {{ end }}
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
        {{ $p := rioz $m }}
        {{ $m := sub $m 1 }}
        {{ $end2 := add (add $end1 $divide) $p }}
        {{ range (slice . $end1 $end2) }}
        {{ template "moviebox" . }}
        {{ end }}
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
        {{ $p := rioz $m }}
        {{ $m := sub $m 1 }}
        {{ $end3 := add (add $end2 $divide) $p }}
        {{ range (slice . $end2 $end3) }}
        {{ template "moviebox" . }}
        {{ end }}
    </div>
</div>
{{ end }}
```